# Angular http put request does not work and gives me an error 500

Tags: angular, typescript, localhost, http-put

I built a Website using Angular and it works so far. I can get data from a localhost running, but I can't put any data on it. It always gives me the error 500 (picture might help).
[See Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uADH.png)

My put request looks like this:

```
public setParkingEntries(x: any) {
return this.http.put(this.configUrl + "/api/tickets/SaveTicket", x); }
```

And

```
this.parkingService.setParkingEntries(this.dataX).subscribe (data =>  { })
```

Now, `this.dataX` is an Object Array containing all Data I want to upload to the server. Note that the first code is in my `parking.service.ts` file and the second code is in my `parking.component.ts` file.

Can anyone tell me how to either fix this or at least tell me what the issue might be?

Thanks for any replies in advance.

Comment: Please post code and not pictures. There is no way for me to translate that message.

Comment: Error code 500 would mean that the *angular put request* is actually working, the request has reached the server, and the server encountered an unexpected error while processing the request (500 internal server error). You should try to fix the issue on the server side.

Comment: The error message sent by your server can also mean that your object binder was unable to decode the payload. My guess is that you need to send some headers with your put request, to let the server know you're sending JSON (`Content-Type: application/json`). I believe the default for `put` is something else. Check [this example out](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#add-heroserviceupdatehero). Pass that `httpOptions` as the third parameter of the `http.put` call